# Read-only text stops working after a while

Tags: buffers, debugging, text-properties, read-only-mode

This is a very strange issue and its cause is hard to determine. I often leave Emacs open for days, or even weeks at a time. My current `emacs-uptime` is 9 and a half days. That's pretty normal and sometimes it can be twice as long or longer.

However, sometimes when I run Emacs for this long and I happen to push Emacs particularly hard (running lots of processes, opening big files, using strange settings, etc.) something weird happens after some days. Emacs randomly blinks all of a sudden, like it's doing `redisplay` or something. This lasts for about a second or less. Thereafter, read-only text is not read-only anymore. I mean that ***any*** read-only text ***anywhere*** in Emacs is no longer read-only. REPL prompts, info buffers, help buffers, eshell prompts, buffers set to `view-mode`, any buffer in `read-only-mode`, anything else you can think of.

Basically, all read-only text becomes writable. At all, anywhere. I can accidentally clobber documentation by pressing a key that would normally do nothing or I can accidentally delete a REPL prompt which can screw up all kinds of things when developing. The only way around this issue (that I know of) is to restart Emacs. This is not always a viable solution. As you can see, this is a very annoying and often serious problem. But I cannot find anyone else online who has had this same issue.

So how can I determine what is causing this issue? And more importantly, how can I fix it?

Here is my `emacs-version`:

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 5, x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0, Carbon Version 158 AppKit 1561.4)
 of 2018-07-17
```

I.e., I'm on the [Emacs Mac Port](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/) (by Yamamoto Mitsuharu) version 26.1. Also, my OS is macOS 10.13.6. I am happy to give more information about my setup as it becomes necessary.

Comment: You might get some help here (hope so), but you might also get some help with `M-x report-emacs-bug`. In either case, you probably will need to provide more info, preferably a recipe to repro the problem (which I realize would likely be hard to come up with).

Comment: Is this true for buffers where `buffer-read-only` is `t` and `inhibit-read-only` is `nil`? Is it true for text that has non-`nil` property `read-only`?

Comment: @Drew As I was testing those conditions, I realized that `inhibit-read-only` was set to `t`. After I reset this variable to `nil` using `(setq inhibit-read-only nil)`, the problem seems to have gone away completely. I was not aware of this variable so I did not check it. If you make this an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Done...........

Comment: To my knowledge, `inhibit-read-only` is intended to be dynamically-bound in order to temporarily allow modification of read-only text (where appropriate).  In order for it to end up set 'permanently', I would speculate that some badly-behaved code is neither setting it in a temporary scope nor using `condition-case` to ensure it gets restored, and it got left that way after an error occurred?  Someone might be able to suggest a valid reason for it, but it certainly sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @phils Yes, this is quite probably a bug in some 3rd-party package or in Emacs itself. Thank you for the elaboration on what specifically could be causing this errant behavior. I may try to investigate the cause of this bug at some point in the future (and if I do I may update this question), but for the time being, I am satisfied with knowing the culprit of the problem and how to fix it when it rears its ugly head.

Comment: D'oh. I meant `unwind-protect` rather than `condition-case` in my previous comment.

Comment: @phils Gotcha, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this true for buffers where `buffer-read-only` is `t` and `inhibit-read-only` is `nil`? Is it true for text that has non-`nil` property `read-only`?

Check each of those situations, and if you still see a problem then consider filing a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Thank you! As I wrote in my comment above, `inhibit-read-only` was bound globally and was thus causing the problem. After I reset the variable to `nil`, the problem was fixed. This is probably a bug, but now I at least know what the bug is and how to squash it ;)